# COUNTIFS with or condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of cities (this is a simplified version)

London
Manchester
Nottingham

I want to say something like (Obviously formula is not correct, is just to show what I am trying to do)

```
=COUNTIFS(MachineData!$X:$X,"Y",MachineData!$N:$N,"*london*" OR MachineData!$N:$N, "*Manchester*" OR MachineData!$N:$N,"*Nottingham*")
```

Basically, I want to count if its London OR Manchester OR Nottingham but also if X:X is Y

How can I do this without having to repeat the same instruction 3 times? is there a way to do this where I can tell it to check all the conditions for the cities at once?

Update: I have been trying something like

```
=COUNTIFS(MachineData!$X:$X,"Y",SUM(COUNTIFS(MachineData!$N:$N,{"London","*Manchester*","Oxford","*Nottingham*"})))
```

But this is not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to a solution yourself. Try:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(MachineData!X:X,"Y",MachineData!N:N,{"*london*","*manchester*","*nottingham*"}))
```

Comment: best solution, i was waiting for JvdV to answer

Comment: Thanks, so I tried this 

=SUM(COUNTIFS(MachineData!$N:$N,{"London","*Manchester*","*London*","*Oxford*"},MachineData!$X:$X,"Y"))

And it works perfectly, the issue is that I actually want to count everything that is not on those cities, but I am not sure of where to position the <> for a wildcard, I have tried "<>*London*" and "*<>London*" but it does not seem to work, not sure of what I am not doing right

Comment: Subtract the above from a total of arguments: `=COUNTA(MachineData!X:X)-<TheAboveAnswer>`. Btw, it's best to actually tell us in your question what it is you want to do or everyone else to @Sam

Answer (score 1):

edit: Use @JvdV solution. Far more elegant, less wall of text.

I created a small table as an example, five lines long reading london, manchester, nottingham, cardiff, london. The table name is table1, the column header I used was "target city"

With that in mind, this will bring the desired results into a single cell.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(Table1[Target city],"london"),COUNTIF(Table1[Target city],"manchester"),COUNTIF(Table1[Target city],"nottingham"))
```

Result = 4

Warning: Depending on the length of the target cities you want to bring in and how frequently that list changes this might become prohibitively large/time consuming.

If you need something that will dynamically scale based of a changing list of cities you want to look for, something like python may be a better solution.

Comment: What about if I also want to add the condition of MachineData!$X:$X,"Y"?

I was trying to do something like

=COUNTIFS(MachineData!$X:$X,"Y",SUM(COUNTIFS(MachineData!$N:$N,{"London","*Manchester*","Oxford","*Nottingham*"})))

But thats not working

Comment: This ignores the requirement `MachineData!$X:$X,"Y"`

Comment: @Sam I'm having trouble understanding what the result you're looking for is and the underlying data set. If you had an X column value of Y and an N column value of London, would you want that counted as 1 or 2? I'm assuming 1 but prefer to check before I tinker.

Answer (score 0):

No, COUNTIFS is restricted to AND and cannot use OR.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was trying to avoid because otherwise the fomula will be way too long

Comment: This is not what Sam is requesting

Answer (score 0):

[image]

=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table2[Category 2],"Y",Table2[Category 1],{"London","Manchester","Nottingham"}))

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

[image: named ranges]

There are a couple of ways to crack this question:

Solution1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((N:N=City1)+(N:N=City2)+(N:N=City3))*(X:X=Criteria1))
```

For this type of question, I normally use **SUMPRODUCT** as a first instinct, but it is not as fast as using **SUM+COUNTIFS** if you are working on a large dataset.

Solution2:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(N:N,Cities,0)*MATCH(X:X,Criteria1,0)))
```

Instead of checking on individual cities, it would be faster to put the cities in a named range and check all of them at once and then add the results up.

Solution3:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(X:X,Criteria1,N:N,TRANSPOSE(Cities)))
```

This is the solution proposed by JvdV using named ranges.

Solution4:

```
=SUM((N:N=TRANSPOSE(Cities))*(X:X=Criteria1))
```

This will do the trick too, but I am not sure how it compares to **SUM+COUNTIFS** in terms of calculation efficiency on a large dataset.

[image: Solutions]